# spark rdd mapValues

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Question:

```
x = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs:///user/ydzhao/2017/05/01")
print(x.collect())
# [('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200100.txt', 'dkdksfk fjd 123 765\ndsfdf dfgd 53 23\n'),
   ('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200200.txt', 'sdsddfdsk gfrged 454 7455')]

count = x.mapValues(lambda line:len(line)).collect()
print(count)
# [('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200100.txt', 37), ('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200200.txt', 25)]
```

I just want to calculate every file's ‘number of rows’，for example like that:

```
[('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200100.txt', 'dkdksfk fjd 123 765\ndsfdf dfgd 53 23\n'),
   ('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200200.txt', 'sdsddfdsk gfrged 454 7455')]
```

but when I use `count = x.mapValues(lambda line:len(line)).collect()` I get the result like:

```
[('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200100.txt', 37),
 ('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200200.txt', 25)]
```

actually, I need:

```
[('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200100.txt', 2),
 ('hdfs://meihui/user/ydzhao/2017/05/01/TRAFF_20170501200200.txt', 1)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.splitlines`:

```
x.mapValues(lambda s: len(s.splitlines()))
```